# Python - Readfile and SSH

Tags: python

I currently have this code to read a .CSV file, and SSH into a router with the hostname/IP listed on the .CSV

The problem is that the file reads the line as "192.168.2.1/r/n"
Example: ('Node', 4, '...Checking IP Address...', 'CPE-SIBFOPASO-103179-01\r\n')

Can you please help?

Code Sample:

```
nodenum=1
f=open('Routers.csv', 'r') #Ficheiro com Hostnames
c=f.readlines()

with open('Output.csv','wb') as f: #Ficheiro novo com o output
    write = csv.writer(f)
    write.writerow(['Hostname', "Cellular"])

    for i in c :
        print ("Node", nodenum, "...Checking IP Address...", i)
        try:
            Connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(ip=i, device_type="cisco_ios" , username="y", password="x", verbose=Fal
```

se)

Comment: Perhaps you should use `.strip` to remove new line characters

Comment: Thanks! c=f.readlines.strip()?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up achieving the result I wanted by changing the code to this:

```
f=open('Routers.csv', 'r') 
c=f.read()
file_as_list = c.splitlines()
```